# Weird form submit with id or name of submit btn as querystring?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, submit, action

simple normal form that's submitting an action.

```
<form id="myAppSearchForm" method="get" action="<%= search_path %>">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="input-inside-label">
            <label for="myAppSearchForm_searchstring">Search weavr</label>
            <input id="myAppSearchForm_searchstring" name="search" class="search" title="enter search term" />
        </div>
        <button class="btn" name="myAppSearchFormSubmit" type="submit">GO</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

however I don't get why the ID or name attribute of the Submitbutton gets added to the query string?

Like so: `myurl/search?search=test&myAppSearchFormSubmit=`

Any idea why that could happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's just how forms work. Drop the name attribute and the value of that button won't be included in the params for the form submission.

Answer (score 1):

Change it to an `<input type="submit" name="myAppSearchFormSubmit">` and it should show up. `<button>` tags are really a form element, though they show up the same as an `<input type="button">` for the most part, so they don't really have any affect on a form.